# Bubble sort not working for dynamically allocated array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting, dynamic

I created a dynamically allocated array of strings with 1280 strings in the array and I am trying to sort it using bubble sort. Max is 1280. I am having trouble on the bubbleSort function as it keeps giving me a segmentation fault: 11.

```
   char** f = calloc(max, sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        f[i] = malloc(349);
    }

    i = 0;
    while(i < max)
    {
        strtok(d[i], del);
        strtok(NULL, del);
        strtok(NULL, del);      
        f[i] = strtok(NULL, del);
        i++;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {   
        printf("%s\n", f[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    bubbleSort(&f[max], max);
}

void bubbleSort(char *d[], int length)
{
    int i, unsorted;
    char* temp;

    do {
        unsorted = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
            if( strcmp(d[i], d[i+1]) > 0 )
            {
                temp = d[i];
                d[i] = d[i+1];
                d[i+1] = temp;
                unsorted = 1;
            }
```

Comment: There isn't a need to `malloc` `f[i]` if you are going to use `f[i] = strtok(NULL, del);`. This leads to a *memory leak*.

Comment: `bubbleSort(&f[max], max);` is wrong. You are passing the address of an invalid memory location

Comment: @CoolGuy if I took out malloc f[i] how would I pass the array to bubbleSort?

Comment: A part of your code is missing. I think the key is how your `d` variable is allocated.

Comment: @sukurity , Doesn't `bubbleSort(f, max);` work?